# Новая причина в списке "Не по теме"

Tags: предложение, тематика

Предлагаю перенести с большого SO следующую причину:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
>   for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily
>   for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Актуальна для вопросов в стиле "После установки обновления не грузится Винда".

В общем ответе ниже можно исправить перевод. Также обсуждаем вопрос, следует ли упоминать сообщество Super User, поскольку оно англоязычное.

Comment: Имеет ли смысл добавлять данный комментарий в контексте [обновленной страницы справки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) и [вопроса о тематиках SU и SF на Stack Overflow на русском](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/)?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky думаю да.

Comment: На мой взгляд, текущий перевод противоречит принятому решению о вопросах по системному администрированию и сложному ПО.

Comment: По-прежнему актуально.

Answer (score 3):

> Вопросы о компьютерном оборудовании и программном обеспечении,
>   которые не касаются инструментов, используемых в программировании и
>   профессиональном системном администрировании,
>   являются на Stack Overflow на русском вопросами не по теме.

Comment: 1. Слово "общие" лишнее. Во-первых, потому что в оригинале "general" к другому слову прицеплено. Во-вторых, потому что "общие" посты — это вики, возникает неоднозначность. 2. Stack Overflow -> Stack Overflow на русском.